# Listview not rendering right on the second time the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, listviewitem

I'm having some issues with JqueryMobile. I load a page and create the Listview on the fly. The first time the page loads, the list gets rendered fine, when I go back to the previous page and click on the same link, the listview doesn't render as a list view, just as link. I have multiple pages on the same doc, so I refer the pages by id. Code below.

Where the list gets built.

```
    function getDays(mon){
        var total = 0;
        $("#h1").text(sites);
        $("#perDay").empty();
        $.getJSON('/cf/cfc/statistics.cfc?method=PagesPerDay', { site: sites , months : mon}, function(qPress) {
            $.each(qPress, function(i, item) {
                total = total + item.pages;
                $("#perDay").append('<li id="' + item.dayname +'"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="getDays();">' + item.dayname + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + item.pages + '</span></a></li>');
            }); 
            $("#perDay").append('<li data-theme="b" class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c ui-li-has-count">Total' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + total + '</span></li>');               
            ChangePage("#pageDays", 'pop', sites);
        });
    }
```

The html

```
    <div data-role="page" id="pageDays">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <a href="#razzberry" data-icon="back" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h1 id="h1"></h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content"> 
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Pages Viewed Per Day</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="perDay"></ul>  
        </div>  
    </div><!-- /page -->
```

I tried to put `$("#perMonth").listview("refresh");` after the loop but I got
Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh

I am using the jQuery Mobile 1.0

Comment: I don't think you're calling ChangePage correctly? Look at the docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html maybe $.mobile.changePage( "#pageDays", { transition: "pop"} );

Comment: Can you post a link to your code online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to solve it is to use

```
$("#pageDays").page('destroy').page();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Inaki thank you for reply. In my example, I destroyed page(div_list_id ul) after then append item.

```
<div id="div_loc_list"></div>

// firstly destroy ul
$("#div_loc_list ul").page('destroy').page();
var list_content ='';
for (var i=0; i < posArray.length; i++) {
        var ltitle = posArray[i].title;
        list_content += '<li><a href="#direction_page">'+ltitle+'</a></li>';
 }
$('#div_loc_list').append('<ul data-role="listview">'+list_content+'</ul>');
```